# How to convert 14 bit Hex to Decimal

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I need to be able to convert `047C1BEA3A2480` into Decimal. This should convert to `1262359242482816`. I have a large amount of hex numbers that need converting so would need a formula or VB script.

I have tried some things including a VB Module, however with this I need to prefix the number with 0X but then gives me a decimal number that is out by 4.

Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Use the inbuilt `CDec` function

```
Debug.Print CDec("&H" & "047C1BEA3A2480")
```

This will give you `1262359242482816`

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for this. How could I do this on a mass scale?

Comment: You can either use a for loop if you are doing it VBA or create a UDF for this

Answer (score 1):

Split into 2 7-digits and use the HEX2DEC function. Unfortunately, Excel cannot handle that big a number, so it is rounding when you put it back in Excel. For exmaple, try to paste the decimal version into Excel. But if you want the formula anyway.

```
=HEX2DEC(LEFT(A4,7))*16^7+HEX2DEC(RIGHT(A4,7))
```

Otherwise, use Siddarth's solution and put it in Excel as Text.